# Lock-free Bloom-like probabilistic data structures implemented in C

Tags: c, linux, lock-free, bloom-filter

I'm writing variant of lock-free skiplist designed for multithreaded environment, and found that searching of none existent elements could be verified efficiently by applying Bloom filter-like data structure. In case of simply inserting elements into list lock-free Bloom filter as in [link](https://gist.github.com/basefook/3326413) seems to be efficient, but this algorithm prohibits removal of elements. Counting Bloom filter or Chuchoo filter would suffice, but i'm not aware of them being implemented in c as lock-free algorithms.

Are there any lock-free probabilistic data structures similar to Bloom filter 
that tell if variable is a member of given set implemented in C?

Comment: I haven't looked closely at it but couldn't you implement a counting bloom filter with atomic add and subtract operations? Then, an item is not added to the bloom filter until the last atomic add operation is finished. Likewise, an item is "removed" from a bloom filter after the first subtract operation succeeds.

Comment: @tinger surly it makes sense but from my previous experience with lock free algos they seem to be none trivial to implement, would like to have some reference